# Get sum of ListView column when datapager is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview with more than 6000 rows. I am using a DataPager to show 100 columns in Page. But I want total of Amount Column in a Textbox. I am subscribed to DataBound event and calculating the total from there. But, It's giving me the total per Page. How can I get the total of all rows.

```
protected void FilterListView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double curTotal = 0;
        foreach (ListViewItem lit in FilterListView.Items)
        {
            if (lit.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
            {

                LinkButton lbTotAm = (LinkButton)lit.FindControl("LinkButton22");

                if (lbTotAm != null)
                {
                    double curAmt = 0;
                    if (!double.TryParse(lbTotAm.Text, out  curAmt)) curAmt = 0;
                    curTotal += curAmt;
                }
            }
        }
        filterTotalAmt.Text = curTotal.ToString("N2");
    }
```

Comment: So you want a column describing the entire data set to be displayed on every row? If your "total amount" equals 500, every single row will display 500 in the "total amount" column?

Answer (score 0):

You can get sub item from list view and calculate the count Example is shown below.

```
decimal gtotal = 0;
        foreach (ListViewItem lstItem in orderlist.Items)
        {
            gtotal += decimal.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[3].Text);//Depending on your column position change this line
        }
        grandtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(gtotal);
```

Comment: This will iterate only 100 rows since I am using DataPager with 100 rows per page.